# Div with background color overlaps div with links

Tags: css, html, overlap

I am having a little bit of problem with two divs using `z-index`. I have created a `div` called topbar with `z-index: 1`, and another one called "socialbuttons" with `z-index: 2` which has image links to Facebook and Twitter. However, the topbar overlaps the soc buttons and I can neither see nor click the social buttons. I have scoured the internet and tried everything I could but I am still stuck with the same issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my HTML code

```
<div id ="topbar" 
    style="height: 56px; width:95%; background-color:#002268; z-index:-1; position:relative; top: -6px; left: -1px;">
</div>

<div id= "socialbuttons" 
    style= "position:relative; z-index: 1000; top: 15px; left: 770px; height:53px; width: 249px; margin-bottom: 0px;">

    <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">

    <img alt="" src="images/twitter.png" 


        style="position:absolute; top: 0px; left:40%; height:49px; width: 59px; z-index:1000"/></a><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="images/fbook.png" 

style="position:relative; width:50px; height:49px; top: 0px; z-index:1000"/></a></div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/BQBaV/)

Comment: Are you using any external CSS file? Because your code works fine for me.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/chankeypathak/29sk4/1/

Comment: I have removed the css file but still no luck. It works just fine in the design mode of VS 2010, but does not work in any of my browsers. I am really stumped!

Comment: Are you looking to place the social media icons in the top bar section ? If so, why can you put the code inside the div topbar ?

Comment: I have actually tried that too. Still no luck. <div id ="topbar" 
    style="height: 56px; width:95%; background-color:#002268; z-index:-1; position:relative; top: -6px; left: -1px;">
    <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="images/twitter.png" 
            style="position:absolute; top: 0px; left:40%; height:49px; width: 59px; z-index:1000; float:right" /></a>

        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="images/fbook.png" 
        style="position:relative; width:50px; height:49px; top: 0px; z-index:1000"/></a>

</div>

Comment: I have actually found that the source of the problem is firefox. The adblocker was blocking social media images. Once I have disabled that, all of the codes work just fine. Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
<div id ="topbar" style="height: 56px; width:95%; background-color:#002268; z-index:-1; position:relative; top: -6px; left: -1px;">
    <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
        <img alt="" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/yooicons_set01_socialbookmarks/48/social_twitter_box_white.png" style="float:right; height:49px; width: 59px;"/>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
        <img alt="" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/yooicons_set01_socialbookmarks/48/social_facebook_box_white.png" style="width:50px; height:49px;float:right;"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BQBaV/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just remove position relative from socialbuttons

[Here is the working link](http://jsfiddle.net/54NRq/)

```
 <div id="socialbuttons" style="z-index: 1000; top: 15px; left: 770px; height:53px; width:   249px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
```

Comment: Well I can see it working normally in design mode but it does not work in runtime https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1028x56q90/545/cnpz.jpg   runtime screenshot https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1306x110q90/401/f3xx.jpg

Comment: Then your other structural styling are creating problems , if its working fine in design mode